# How to avoid BackgroundTransfer in WinRT automatically decompress gzip?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, windows-runtime

The [DownloadOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.downloadoperation%28v=win.10%29.aspx) in Windows Store Apps API always decompress gz content when I specify an http URI. Is there a way to avoid that, like setting the [DecompressionMethods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.decompressionmethods.aspx) of the underlying HttpRequest?

Comment: Where do you read or experience that the DownloadOperation always decompress gz content ?

Comment: I just experienced it in a small project I wrote. I could not find any documentation or comment about it.
 If I use a http address to set the URI it will always decompress the gz I download. If I use a ftp address it will not.